# Is it possible to create a bitmap from two bitmaps in android?

Tags: android

HI friends.

Consider am having two bitmaps a rectangle bitmap and a text bitmap. Now i want to create another bitmap using those two bitmap ( Rectangle and Text ). Is it possible to create a new bitmap using some other bitmaps. If so please advise me or give other some valuable ideas regarding this.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Code example: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4611012/how-to-composecombine-two-photo-image-in-android/4614265#4614265

Answer (score 2):

You can create a BitmapDrawable from your rectangular bitmap using [this](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#BitmapDrawable%28android.content.res.Resources,%20android.graphics.Bitmap%29) constructor, and then override the [draw](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/drawable/BitmapDrawable.html#draw%28android.graphics.Canvas%29) method so that you can draw the text bitmap over the other one. Just use one of the [drawBitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Canvas.html#drawBitmap%28android.graphics.Bitmap,%20float,%20float,%20android.graphics.Paint%29) methods of the Canvas class.

Answer (score 0):

You can create a [new Bitmap](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/graphics/Bitmap.html#createBitmap%28int,%20int,%20android.graphics.Bitmap.Config%29) and then loop through both of your source Bitmaps.  At every point, if the text image's pixel is white (or a known background colour), use the rectangle's pixel color.  If the text image's pixel is black (or a known text colour), use the text's color.